# exclude src/main/java from compiling with maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, maven-compiler-plugin

Is anybody known how to remove a Source roots from maven-compiler-plugin ?

```
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  C:\Workspace\Dev01\Internet_Login\src\main\java
[DEBUG]  C:\Workspace\Dev01\Internet_Login\target\generated-sources\delombok
```

Because I generate source with lombok-maven-plugin from **C:\Workspace\Dev01\Internet_Login\src\main\java** but the maven-compiler-plugin use both Source roots and i get a compilation error.

After compiling, I use Aspectj so I need to do that this way, 'cause Lombok and Aspectj are "incompatible".

Is anybody got a solution.

**EDIT :**

I've got a solution. Just define the sourceDirectory in build and the compiler gonna use this directory.

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/delombok</sourceDirectory>
    ...
</build>
```

Thx

Comment: Have you considered placing your sources elsewhere? I think I've seen `src/main/lombok`.

Comment: I'm not sure but it sounds as your setup is wrong cause lombok is usually setup as annotation processor? Can you please post your pom file..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and how it helps the community answer your question. If nobody can reproduce your problem, answers will necessarily be speculative. This does not help you much, unless you get lucky and someone speculates correctly by chance.

Answer (score 0):

did you try with excludes ?

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>src/main/java/</exclude>
        </excludes>                  
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, I've already try this. I don't know why but the maven-compiler-plugin still compiling all sources

Answer (score 0):

As Chrylis suggested, you ought to place any classes with Lombok annotations into `src/main/lombok` when using that plugin. This is clearly documented on its [usage page](http://anthonywhitford.com/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/usage.html).

There is also a [sample project](https://github.com/awhitford/lombok.maven/tree/master/test-maven-lombok/src/main) where you can see how plain Java classes without Lombok annotations are placed in `src/main/java` and the Lombok targets in `src/main/lombok`.

Just follow the instructions and you should be fine with regard to Maven Compiler plugin. As for AspectJ, it depends on how you want to weave your aspects (compile time, binary weaving, load time) and whether the aspects reside in the same or another module.